# Issue with external styles: getting StackOverflowError after upgrading to JasperReports 6.3.0

Tags: java, jasper-reports

So I am in the process of upgrading jasper reports off of a very old version. This was from 3.7.6 to 6.3.0, so yeah, lots of changes. For the most part, it wasn't as bad as I expected it to be. Needed to update some deprecated stuff around file resolvers and exporters, but most everything works and visual layout of reports is the same.

The only problem that I've had and have been unable to solve is around setting default styles. We do this in a number of reports and is giving me an error that I cannot make sense of.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE jasperTemplate
            PUBLIC "-//JasperReports//DTD Template//EN"
            "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jaspertemplate.dtd">

    <jasperTemplate>

        <style name="gothamBase" fontName="Monospaced" forecolor="#5d5c5c" vAlign="Top"></style>

        <style name="gothamMedium" style="gothamBase" fontSize="12" isDefault="true" ></style>

    </jasperTemplate>
```

So this is an example of style that is giving me issues. When we attempt to compile a report that references this, I get:

```
threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle.getStyle(JRBaseStyle.java:338)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.StyleResolver.getBaseStyle(StyleResolver.java:109)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.StyleResolver.getFontName(StyleResolver.java:1191)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle.getFontName(JRBaseStyle.java:594)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.StyleResolver.getFontName(StyleResolver.java:1194)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle.getFontName(JRBaseStyle.java:594)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.StyleResolver.getFontName(StyleResolver.java:1194)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle.getFontName(JRBaseStyle.java:594)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.StyleResolver.getFontName(StyleResolver.java:1194)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle.getFontName(JRBaseStyle.java:594)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.StyleResolver.getFontName(StyleResolver.java:1194)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle.getFontName(JRBaseStyle.java:594)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.StyleResolver.getFontName(StyleResolver.java:1194)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle.getFontName(JRBaseStyle.java:594)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.StyleResolver.getFontName(StyleResolver.java:1194)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle.getFontName(JRBaseStyle.java:594)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.StyleResolver.getFontName(StyleResolver.java:1194)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseStyle.getFontName(JRBaseStyle.java:594)
```

To exclude other factors, I gutted the report so that it was empty with just a reference to the template that had the above style. I removed all other styles from the template file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="title" pageWidth="792" pageHeight="612" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="792" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <template><![CDATA["styles.jrtx"]]></template>

</jasperReport>
```

Still have the issue even after narrowing it down to this. For some reason it does not like me setting a default style when that style also references a parent style. But looking at the jasper documentation, what I'm doing here is valid.

I found this http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/535452/javalangstackoverflowerror, which had a similar error. But we are not using javaflow. Just to be sure I've added that change to log4j so that javaflow is not on debug, that didn't change anything. Also tried excluding javaflow from our pom, no luck either.

Any help?

Comment: The two styles are pretty much all that are in the jrtx. I deleted everything else to narrow down what is the problem. I updated the code for the jrtx to include the rest of the xml that is in there.

Comment: Is that the entire `.jrxml` file as well? If not, please post as much as you can, including any inline styles and elements with references to any and all styles.

Comment: The short snippet of the jrxml file and the jrtx are all that are there. I deleted everything else in attempts to figure out what the hell the problem was.

Comment: There is insufficient information to answer this question. Please add more details. Be as exact as possible. Include directory and file paths, full file contents, any Java code (if applicable), font file references, and anything else you think might be helpful.

Comment: @user603682 Looks like styles have cyclic dependency. Try to delete styles and create it again in *JSS*, for example. Are you sure that you don't have the styles with the same names in *jrxml* files (reports templates)?

Comment: The cyclic dependency that Alex K is talking about comes from the style definitions.  gothamMedium refers to gothamBase as parent type, and gothamBase falls back to gothamMedium because the latter is the default style.  Such dependency is not handled properly by JasperReports.  One way to break the chain is to set the net.sf.jasperreports.styles.inherit.from.default property to false (in your jasperreports.properties file or programmatically).