# Issue with external styles: Upgrade from 5.2.0 to 6.2.2 version of JasperReports causing StackOverflowError while report generation

Tags: java, jasper-reports

We have recently upgraded JasperReports version from 5.2.0 to 6.2.2. After that Report generation failing with below stack overflow error.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.StyleResolver.getPadding(StyleResolver.java:1533) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseLineBox.getPadding(JRBaseLineBox.java:228) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.StyleResolver.getPadding(StyleResolver.java:1541) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseLineBox.getPadding(JRBaseLineBox.java:228) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.StyleResolver.getPadding(StyleResolver.java:1541) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseLineBox.getPadding(JRBaseLineBox.java:228) ~[jasperreports-javaflow-
..........................
```

After some research i found below interesting details.

We have Two style templates defined in our code one is at platform level and another is project specific.

PlatformStyles.jrtx:

```
style name="genericTextStyle" vAlign="Middle" fontName="DejaVu Sans" fontSize="11"
```

ProjectStyles.jrtx:

```
style name="projectTextStyle" style="genericTextStyle" isDefault="true" fontName="SansSerif" fontSize="8"
```

Above code (style templates) is working as expected in the previous version of JasperReports 5.2.0. Same code is causing the above mentioned error while running the report.

Finally, i have just removed `isDefault="true"` from the ProjectStyles.jrtx file, After that reports are generating without any error.

Even i tried with latest release of JasperReports 6.3.1 , Still facing the same issue!

Is this a bug in JasperReports upgrade OR provided a new way of doing this?

Comment: Looks like a recursion for styles

Comment: Possible duplicate: [StackOverflowError after upgrading to jasper reports 6.3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40270492/876298). Try to use `net.sf.jasperreports.styles.inherit.from.default` as dada67 proposed at post above

Comment: Did you try to debug with attached source code?

Comment: I have tried that, But no luck. Even i want to have the default style in my template. By making that value to false through code may break my functionality.

Comment: Is this the bug introduced in new jasper library?